# block outgoing traffic on specific port without blocking internal traffic

Tags: iptables, proxy, http-proxy

I'm hosting a service on port 3000. Using apache, I made it so `https://git.mywebsite.com` proxies over to `http://mywebsite.com:3000`. Now, if I input the following command:

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j DROP`

It does prevent external users from accessing `http://mywebsite.com:3000`, but now apache can no longer access it internally as well, which means `https://git.mywebsite.com` is down also. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your Apache2 proxy uses `localhost:3000` as the proxy destination.

Best option is to configure your service so that it only binds to `127.0.0.1:3000` address on startup, not to `0.0.0.0:3000`. This prevents anyone from outside connecting to that service.

Second option is to use `iptables` as follows:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i <IFNAME> -p tcp --dport 3000 -j DROP
```

Where `<IFNAME>` is your internet facing interface name.